# ¿Cómo pasar datos de mysql a una tabla en php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

el problema que tengo es el siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
tengo una funcion la cual utilizo en el modelo para obtener los datos de mysql, guardarlos en un arreglo y luego pasar ese arreglo a un controlador

```
public function getPsychologists(){
        $items = [];

        try{
            $query = $this->query('SELECT id, nombre, apellido_p, correo, telefono FROM tbl_usuario WHERE id_rol = 2');

            while($p = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $item = new UserModel();
                $item->setId($p['id']);
                $item->setName($p['nombre']);
                $item->setLastName($p['apellido_p']);
                $item->setEmail($p['correo']);
                $item->setPhone($p['telefono']);

                array_push($items, $item);
            }
            for ($i=0; $i < count($items) ; $i++) { 
                 error_log("UserModel: getPsychologists =>".$items[$i]->getName()." ".$items[$i]->getLastName()." ".$items[$i]->getMothLastName()." ".$items[$i]->getEmail()." ".$items[$i]->getPhone());
            }
            return $items;
            
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e;
        }
    }
```

ese for que tiene el error log me muetra lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
esos son los datos que estan guardados en la bd
lo siguiente que tengo es esta funcion que muestra se supone que deberia pasar el arreglo a texto en formato json

```
function createPsychologistsTable(){
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $res = [];
        $user = new UserModel(); 
        $psychologists = $user->getPsychologists();
        foreach($psychologists as $psychologist){
            array_push($res,$psychologist);
        }
        echo json_encode($res);
    }
```

cuando pongo la direccion en la url para ejecutar la funcion me muetra este resultado del `echo json_encode($res);`  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en la vista tengo el siguiente script

```
<script>
var data = [];
var copydata = [];
    
    async function getData(){
        data = await fetch('http://localhost/departamento-psicologia/psychologists/createPsychologistsTable')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => json);
        this.copydata=[...this.data];
        console.table(data);
        renderData(data);
    }
    getData();
    function renderData(data){
        var databody = document.querySelector('#databody');
        databody.innerHTML = '';
        data.forEach(element => {
            databody.innerHTML += `
            <tr>
                <td>${element.id}</td>
                <td>${element.nombre}</td>
                <td>${element.apellido_p}</td>
                <td>${element.correo}</td>
                <td>${element.telefono}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="<?php echo constant('URL');?>/psychologists/edit/${element.id}" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</a>
                    <a href="<?php echo constant('URL');?>/psychologists/delete/${element.id}" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            `;
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A ojímetro parece que lo tengas bien, pero no vemos los getters ni los setters, y no estoy seguro de lo que hacen ni la estructura completa de una instancia de UserModel.  Para ir descartando cosas quizas tendrías que quitar estas asignaciones: `$item->setId($p['id']);` y cambiarlas por algo así: `$item->id = $p['id'];` y así el objeto no seria del tipo UserModel sino un objeto tal cual (antes predefinelo como `$item = new StdClass();` en cada ciclo, claro).  Ya nos diras si eso arregla algo.

Comment: gracias al final lo hice de otra manera

Answer (score 0):

deje el modelo igual

```
public function getPsychologists(){
        $items = [];

        try{
            $query = $this->query('SELECT id, nombre, apellido_p, correo, telefono FROM tbl_usuario WHERE id_rol = 2');

            while($p = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $item = new UserModel();
                $item->setId($p['id']);
                $item->setName($p['nombre']);
                $item->setLastName($p['apellido_p']);
                $item->setEmail($p['correo']);
                $item->setPhone($p['telefono']);

                array_push($items, $item);
            }

            return $items;
            
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e;
        }
    }
```

el controlador fue el que cambio mas

```
function createPsychologistsTable(){
        $user = new UserModel(); 
        return $user->getPsychologists();
    }
```

en la vista instacio el objeto e itero dentro del cuerpo de la tabla lo que me retorna el metodo del controlador

```
<?php
require_once('controllers/psychologists.php');
$data = new Psychologists();
$pysochologisTable=$data->createPsychologistsTable();
?>
```

```
<table class='table table-striped table-hover' id="tabla">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Apellido</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Telefono</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="databody">
                            <?php foreach ($pysochologisTable as $pyschologist) {
                                
                             ?> 
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $pyschologist->getId(); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $pyschologist->getName() ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $pyschologist->getLastname(); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $pyschologist->getEmail(); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $pyschologist->getPhone(); ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-bs-toggle='modal'
                                        data-bs-target='#staticBackdrop'>
                                        <i class='fa-solid fa-edit'></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' data-bs-toggle='modal'
                                        data-bs-target='#staticBackdrop'>
                                        <i class='fa-solid fa-trash-alt'></i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                             <?php }?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

al final el resultado es este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]